# Doctrine ORM as REST Abstraction for Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, rest, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I´m looking for an **ORM implementation of a Rest Service for ZF2**. I´ve some experience with **Doctrine** in connection with relational Databases and so I would prefer to go with Doctrine for REST/JSON abstraction.

I´ve seen some projects on GitHub for that topic and I want to ask if someone of you already **have experience with that combination** and give me some tipps?!

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: I have not tried myself, but i am aware of a module for rest application based on Doctrine 2 : [zfr-rest](https://github.com/zf-fr/zfr-rest). The maintainers are very reactive.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking...Have you tried using ZF2's AbstractRestfulControllers in conjunction with the doctrine-module for zf2?